# How to pass PHP variable to JavaScript function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this JavaScript function which toggles the visibility of a certain div:

```
function showHideDiv(id){
var obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (obj.style.display=="none"){
  obj.style.display='block';
} else if(obj.style.display=="block"){
  obj.style.display='none';
}
}
```

I have a dynamic div that has the id="pm_message'.$row[0].'". I want to toggle the visibility of this div via the javascript function I mentioned above.

This is my link with the onclick-function:

```
echo '<h1><a onclick="showHideDiv('showHideDiv("message'.$row[0].'")" class="'.$link_class.'" href="'.$profile_url.'">'.$row['title'].'</a></h1>';
```

It doesn't work and I get this error message:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo '<h1><a onclick="showHideDiv('.$row[0].')" class="'.$link_class.'" href="'.$profile_url.'">'.$row['title'].'</a></h1>';
```

It is already in php so you do not need to open another set of php tags.

Comment: Should be `$row[0]`, not `echo $row[0]`.

Comment: @theftprevention you are correct, I have made the correction

Comment: Does not work. I updated my post.

Comment: @drpelz `echo '<h1><a onclick="showHideDiv(\'pm_message'.$row[0].'\')"`

Comment: You keep changing the post, just remember if you start out using single quotes you have to escape them if you want to use them literally